# Is memory allocation of statically allocated arrays always sequential in terms of address value?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

When we create an array on stack , say `int arr[20];` , is it guaranteed that each cell of the array is 4 bytes apart in the memory ? Or it might happen that some of the cells are not allocated sequentially ?

Comment: Yes all array elements must be contiguous

Comment: It is guaranteed that each `int` in the array will be located `sizeof(int)` bytes after the previous `int` in the array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An array is guaranteed to be stored in contiguous memory. Pointer arithmetic is defined in such a way that

```
&arr[i] + 1 == &arr[i + 1]
```

Comment: In the standard (`§7.6.1.1 Subscripting`) this is stated as *"The expression `E1[E2]` is identical (by definition) to `*((E1)+(E2))`"*. (Your answer is correct, just wanted to add the reference)

Comment: So, does this arithmetic apply on dynamically allocated arrays too ?

Comment: @Ayush Yes it does.

Comment: Also, if I am correct, if they didn't maintain the sequence, they would have to save extra information to fetch the cell which is away,  which they don't do . So they "must" remain contiguous.